# Related making Connection in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I used to make connection object every time, then
I open it and after doing it I Close it. This take lot of time. Is there anyway to get rid off   this. In Windows Application ()

Comment: You can make connection to many different things. Could you be a little more specific? Also show your current code, explain what issues you have with it and so on. In short: ask a real question.

Comment: Connection with database (SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ADO.NET you could take advantage of the [connection pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) to avoid opening and closing a physical database connection everytime you want to send a query.